# How to retrieve and alert JSON.stringify

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Im trying to alert a user that the file size is not allowed and the size of the image.

in  my code I'm doing:

```
alert('Error' + [JSON.stringify(err)]);
```

The alert message returns:

```
Error[{"message":"File size not allowed","error":"FILE_SIZE","param":10722753}]
```

I would like the alert to say:

```
File size not allowed 10722753
```

How can I clean up this error message and get the details our of the err object?

Comment: Do you know how to get individual values by key out of an object or array?

Comment: Stringifying the object will convert the entire object to a string. You need to build the message by concatenating the object properties you need to create the message. You can use dot syntax as in `err.message` or bracket syntax as in `err['message']` to access these properties.

Answer (score 3):

```js
var err = {"message":"File size not allowed","error":"FILE_SIZE","param":10722753};

document.write('Error ' + err.message + " " + err.param);
```

You can directly access the JSON properties

```
alert('Error ' + err.message + " " + err.param);
```

Comment: I'm getting undefined undefined now?

Comment: @user520300 Remove any reference to `JSON.stringify(err)`. You need `err` to remain an object not be a string.

Comment: Exactly, make sure err is a valid JSON object and not a string, check the edit.

Comment: if i alert err by itself i get [object Object]  if i alert err.message i get undefined

Comment: can you execute console.log(err) in and add the result in you console to your question in order to verify what is wrong and what is exactly is `err`?

Comment: oh, then your variable is being set as an array with first property as the JSON object, do you really need the JSON object within an array?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the fields of your JSON object:

```
alert(err.message + " " + err.param );
```

Comment: I'm getting undefined undefined now?

Comment: I assumed that "err" was a valid JSON... this means that it isn't a real JSON object. When I meet this problem the best solution is to whatch into your object, e.g. concole.log(err)... if it is a JSON object my code is able to work, otherwhise you need to understand how to access to your object (it depends upon it is a json object's representation, a javascript pure object, an array, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help you.

```
var err=[{"message":"File size not allowed","error":"FILE_SIZE","param":10722753}];

alert("Error Message: "+err[0].message);
```

You will get:

**Error Message: File size not allowed**